# Importing initialisation functions in ReactJS / React-Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am currently refactoring a project by abstracting all *init* functions outside of the actual React component.

These *init* functions simply hydrate the Redux store and set some cookies.

Let's say I store them in a file called **AppInit.js**, as follows:

```
..

hydrateRedux = () => {
  //
}

setCookies = () => {
  //
}}

..
```

What is the approach I should take to be able to call this initialisation file to run **all** the functions?

I was thinking of doing some like an *actions* file, however I prefer if I just call the file to run the functions automatically rather than calling them one by one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be your `init.js` file:

```
// init.js
export const firstInitFunction = () => console.log('init first')

export const secondInitFunction = () => console.log('init second')

export const thirdInitFunction = () => console.log('init third')
```

This can be your `index.js` file (or whatever file needs to call functions from `init.js`:

```
// index.js file
import * as inits from './init.js'; 

inits.forEach(init => init())
```

There are many other ways to do this. This one is probably the most straightforward.

You can also execute the `inits.forEach(init => init())` inside the `init.js` file. That way your `index.js` file can look like this:

```
// index.js file
import './init.js'
```